# ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedStat

Tags: android, classcastexception

App crashes on Samsung galaxy devices randomly.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4073)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:172)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1314)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
           at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRestoreInstanceState(Toolbar.java:1048)
           at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:13757)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2855)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2861)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2861)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2861)
           at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:13735)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1936)
           at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:997)
           at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:969)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1144)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2382)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4073)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:172)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1314)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: This may be helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961176/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-abssavedstate1-cannot-be-cast-to-and)