# Android - Programmatically adding button, setting ID crashes

Tags: java, android, dynamic, error-handling

I am programmatically adding x amount of buttons to my view depending on a config loaded (lets just use 10 for an example). I create the 10 just fine, and it works when I don't set an ID, or when I use Androids generateId() function, but I want to use my iterator (i) to set the id, so that each value of the iteration matches the button it creates

i.e.

```
(for i=0; i<10; i++)
{
     button.setId(i);
 }
```

I want this so that when I switch fragments, it saves the buttons and I don't recreate them with onCreate. As it stands, I get this error:

```
 01-25 17:46:18.197  13236-13236/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.onRestoreInstanceState(CompoundButton.java:379)
```

Comment: It might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961176/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-abssavedstate1-cannot-be-cast-to-and

Comment: Why dont you use `button.setTag("yourID")`

Comment: Well if I give it an ID, doesn't it save the fact that it's been created in the Saved Bundle? Otherwise I'm just creating 10 new buttons each time I switch back to the fragment.

Comment: I think your problem would be settings same id to another views. Make sure your activity have configChanges to spesific cases in manifest and handle your solution in onConfigChange.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generateViewId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) within your for and create a method to get your buttons from an ArrayList.

Try this:

```
public class YourClass {

    public ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    public void generateButtons(){
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
            ids.add(View.generateViewId());
            // your code to create the button
            button.setId(ids.get(i));
        }
    }

    public Button getButton(int index){
        return (Button) findViewById(ids.get(index));
    }

}
```

Or just create an ArrayList of buttons...

Comment: Thanks...I actually just ended up having my unique ID start at 400 and iterate through the amount of buttons, I guess there was a conflict of IDs between another id/view....lol. I spent quite a bit of time looking into the casting and what not on other posts, and I guess I just wanted a corresponding id between button and uniqueID but this will do. Thanks!