# Android java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState

Tags: java, android

This  symptoms are the same as here: [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961176/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-abssavedstate1-cannot-be-cast-to-and)

But it's not the right solution.
There are no files with the same name as resource ids:

Current working dir below is `app/src/main/res`:

```
git ls-files . | cut -d "/" -f 2  | sed 's/\.xml//g' > /tmp/a
cat values/ids.xml | cut -d "\"" -f 2 > /tmp/b
cat /tmp/a | while read line; do grep -w $line /tmp/b; done
```

This yields no results.

Also, there are no duplicate ids within `values/ids.xml`

```
cat values/ids.xml | cut -d "\"" -f 2 | sort | wc -l
96
cat values/ids.xml | cut -d "\"" -f 2 | sort | uniq | wc -l
96
```

The exception occurs when I restart the app via an Alarm.

```
    ...
    alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000,
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(
                    this, LauncherActivity.class), 0));
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    ...
```

And then it crashes before LauncherActivityies `onCreate`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ba.euroexpress.izvidjac/ba.euroexpress.traffictool.android.activites.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2779)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1590)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.onRestoreInstanceState(CompoundButton.java:563)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:17726)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3751)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3751)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3751)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3751)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3751)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:17704)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:415)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3244)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7019)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1590) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

What is causing this behavior?
It happens on low memory situations and when restarting it the app in this fashion.

Also note I don't use the `CompoundButton` class anywhere.

```
git grep CompoundButton
// no results
```

Comment: did you sort this out? I am facing the same issue

Comment: I infact did. When manually creating a View inside a child, i called the constructor of the child with the attributeSet from the parent giving them the same ID effectively.

Comment: @Gala you find any solution?

Comment: @bhardwaj see if you pass around a AttributeSet to a child accidentally

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the HorizontalScrollView

```
android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.HorizontalScrollView$SavedState
```

And I solved it by adding unique ids to the views in the custom ViewGroup

```
horizontalScrollView.id = View.generateViewId()
```