# HorizontalScrollView is crashing onRestoreInstance

Tags: android, classcastexception, horizontalscrollview

After changing the Height of HorizontalScrollView from

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/topics_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="92dp"/>
```

to

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/topics_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

i started getting this crash

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException
              android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.HorizontalScrollView$SavedState
              android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onRestoreInstanceState (HorizontalScrollView.java:1678)
```

the crash is happening on this method in HorizontalScrollView

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (mContext.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        // Some old apps reused IDs in ways they shouldn't have.
        // Don't break them, but they don't get scroll state restoration.
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }
    SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;       //*******this line is crashing
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    mSavedState = ss;
    requestLayout();
}
```

i found a similar issue and i suspected that obfuscation is not keeping Parcelable and they suggested to add this to proguard file

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
static ** CREATOR;
}
```

when i looked at my proguard file i found that i have already included the below

```
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable { *; }
```

can anyone distinguish the problem and why it started crashing now when i changed the `android:layout_height`?
does this make sense to anyone?
thanks in advance

EDIT: after reading some similar problems i found this one [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961176/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-abssavedstate1-cannot-be-cast-to-and)
now if you read the answer its saying that using same `android:id` for different view can cause this so it got my attention that i recently added a view  that is included in the same layout with the HorizontalScrollView and that views hold this

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topics_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="92dp"/>
```

Can this be the problem?

Comment: what actually you want to do ?

Comment: @quicklearner i didn't understand your question, obviously i want to find the cause of the crash and remove it.

Comment: i mean what actually you are trying to do , maybe i can provide you better alternate for your requirement :)

Comment: there is really nothing complicated in what i have, there is just a simple layout that holds some views and no problem with that, it's just the crash cause that am trying to find it.

Comment: Hope you find the cause of the crash very soon :)

Comment: @quicklearner thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes absolutely this is because you are using same id for two layouts.

First, Cross check that your application is not reusing the same ID's in two different places.

The `onRestoreInstanceState` has performed the `findViewById` method and the first view to be found was not the HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: i will try to reproduce the scenario to make sure that this is the cause

Comment: @MohammadHaidar Are you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @MohammadHaidar may I know what is the root cause because I am also facing the same.

Comment: @Girish as it's written in the answer i had views in the same layout with the same ID

Comment: @MohammadHaidar in that case IDE itself will show "Duplicate id @+id/viewid, already defined earlier in this layout",but this is different.

Comment: @MohammadHaidar
And also even if you have same id in two different layouts for same view say in layout1.xml for horizontalview id is @+id/viewid1 and layout2.xml for horizontalview  id is again @+id/viewid1.. in both the layouts view and ids are  same..how it will be classcastexception.

Comment: @Girish i had an <include> view that had inside it a view that holds the same id of a view that exist in the same layout with the included layout, so in this case it won't show syntax error.

Comment: @MohammadHaidar yeah in above case it won't but I don't have anything like it's two different layout as I explained earlier.