# Crash when restoring Android state - AbsSavedState cannot be cast

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I receive notifications from Crashlytics about the following crash in my Xamarin.Forms project:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/xxxxx.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to 
android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState
at android.widget.CompoundButton.onRestoreInstanceState(CompoundButton.java:619)
at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:18884)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:18862)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2248)
at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1153)
at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1108)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1266)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2930)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

- Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it.
- I checked that `CompoundButton` is a base class for `Switch` and I've got two switches on my main page.
- I've got only one main activity.
- I use Xamarin.Forms without any custom layouts in Xamarin.Android.
- I don't have any custom actions on state preservation/restoration.
- I checked Xamarin.Forms source code for `SwitchRenderer` and its base classes and I don't see any state preservation code either.

In many questions on Stack Overflow it is claimed that the issue might be caused by duplicated `android:id`, however as I mentioned above, I don't have custom layouts.

---

**Update**

I decided to go deeper with investigation and I started verifying whole state preservation mechanism. Below are my findings:

1. I discovered that whole view hierarchy is stored as pairs `(viewId, state)`. Also it turned out that all views preserve state as `AbsSavedState` only `CompoundButton` stores `CompoundButton.SavedState`. Therefore my guess is that somehow incorrect state was used to restore `CompoundButton`. Sample state:

```
{Bundle[{  android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[{android:views=
{1=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,2=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,
3=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 4=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,     
5=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 6=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
7=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 8=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
9=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 10=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,    
11=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 12=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
13=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 14=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
15=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 16=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,   
17=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 18=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
19=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 20=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
21=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 22=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,   
23=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 24=CompoundButton.SavedState{26e683d checked=false},
25=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 26=CompoundButton.SavedState{8f32832 checked=true}, 
27=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 28=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,   
29=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 30=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
31=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 32=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
33=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 34=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,   
35=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 36=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,
37=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,    
16908290=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983, 
2131558525=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983,    
2131558526=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@e738983}}], 
android:lastAutofillId=1073741825, 
android:fragments=android.app.FragmentManagerState@969a700}]}
```

2. I've got `CompoundButtons` (base class for `Switch`) on two pages: `MainPage` and modal page. After all I thought that maybe this possible mismatch while restoring state is caused by duplicated ids somehow. I decided to write a piece of code to print whole hierarchy with ids. Below you can see `MainPage` and modal page, in total 3 switches. However, there is no duplication here.

```
-- 16908290 - ContentFrameLayout
---- -1 - RelativeLayout
------ -1 - PlatformRenderer
-------- 1 - PageRenderer
---------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------- 2 - ImageRenderer
------------ -1 - CustomScrollViewRenderer
-------------- -1 - ScrollViewContainer
---------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------------ 3 - ImageRenderer
---------------------- 4 - LabelRenderer
---------------------- 5 - LabelRenderer
---------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------------ 6 - ImageRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------------- 7 - LabelRenderer
---------------------- 8 - LabelRenderer
---------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------------ 9 - ImageRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------------ -1 - GaugeChartRenderer
------------------------ 10 - LabelRenderer
------------------------ 11 - LabelRenderer
------------------------ -1 - GaugeChartRenderer
------------------------ 12 - LabelRenderer
------------------------ 13 - LabelRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- 14 - LabelRenderer
-------------------- 15 - LabelRenderer
------------------ -1 - LinearChartRenderer
-------------------- 16 - LinearChart
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- -1 - CustomButtonRenderer
---------------------- 17 - Button
-------------------- -1 - CustomButtonRenderer
---------------------- 18 - Button
-------------------- -1 - CustomButtonRenderer
---------------------- 19 - Button
-------------------- -1 - CustomButtonRenderer
---------------------- 20 - Button
-------------------- -1 - CustomButtonRenderer
---------------------- 21 - Button
-------------------- -1 - CustomButtonRenderer
---------------------- 22 - Button
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------------- 23 - LabelRenderer
---------------------- 24 - LabelRenderer
---------------------- 25 - LabelRenderer
---------------------- 26 - LabelRenderer
---------------------- 27 - LabelRenderer
-------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------------- 33 - LabelRenderer
-------------------------- 34 - LabelRenderer
-------------------------- 35 - LabelRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- -1 - CustomSwitchRenderer
---------------------- 28 - Switch
-------------------- 29 - LabelRenderer
-------------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------------- 36 - ImageRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- -1 - CustomSwitchRenderer
---------------------- 30 - Switch
-------------------- 31 - LabelRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- 37 - ImageRenderer
-------------------- -1 - CustomButtonRenderer
---------------------- 32 - Button
-------- 44 - ModalContainer
---------- -1 - View
---------- 38 - PageRenderer
------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------ 39 - LabelRenderer
------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- 45 - ImageRenderer
---------------- -1 - SearchBarRenderer
------------------ 40 - SearchView
-------------------- 16909226 - LinearLayout
---------------------- 16909225 - AppCompatTextView
---------------------- 16909227 - AppCompatImageView
---------------------- 16909229 - LinearLayout
------------------------ 16909231 - AppCompatImageView
------------------------ 16909232 - LinearLayout
-------------------------- 16909233 - AutoCompleteTextView
-------------------------- 16909228 - AppCompatImageView
------------------------ 16909321 - LinearLayout
-------------------------- 16909230 - AppCompatImageView
-------------------------- 16909235 - AppCompatImageView
-------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------- -1 - ListViewRenderer
------------------ -1 - SwipeRefreshLayout
-------------------- 41 - ListView
---------------------- -1 - Container
---------------------- -1 - Container
------------------------ -1 - DefaultRenderer
-------------------- -1 - ImageView
-------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
---------------- -1 - DefaultRenderer
------------------ -1 - CustomSwitchRenderer
-------------------- 42 - Switch
------------------ 43 - LabelRenderer
```

3. Later I thought that maybe Xamarin's id generation mechanism fails after state restoration. But I checked it and after restoration it is properly increased. I even checked source code in Xamarin.Forms/Platform.cs:

```
internal static int GenerateViewId()
{
    if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 17)
        return global::Android.Views.View.GenerateViewId();
    if (s_id >= 0x00ffffff)
        s_id = 0x00000400;
    return s_id++;
}

static int s_id = 0x00000400;
```

It looks fine, unless there is some race condition. I'm running out of ideas.

---

**Update 2**

I subclassed `Switch` control and overrode `OnRestoreSavedInstance` and strange thing that it's never called on my devices. However, `OnSaveInstanceState` is called. Please mind that I properly simulated state restoration (it is called in `MainActivity`, but doesn't propagate to `Switch`).

I found the reason why it behaves in this way. Please take a look at Android's implementation for `View.dispatchRestoreState`:

```
protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) 
{
    if (mID != NO_ID) {
        Parcelable state = container.get(mID);  // <--- HERE
        if (state != null) {
            // Log.i("View", "Restoreing #" + Integer.toHexString(mID)
            // + ": " + state);
            mPrivateFlags &= ~SAVE_STATE_CALLED;
            onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            if ((mPrivateFlags & SAVE_STATE_CALLED) == 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Derived class did not call super.onRestoreInstanceState()");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xamarin.Forms sets ids automatically by increasing counter. Therefore after creating page it sets ids from `1` to `n`. After another recreation (for example after rotating screen) it sets ids from `n+1` to `2n+1`. Therefore none control will be able to restore its state, because when preserving state it will be saved as state for `id=x`, however after recreating `Activity` this control will have a different id.

Therefore this crash should never occur, because of no state restoration...

---

**Update 3**

I noticed also something strange in Android's implementation. `CompoundButton` has this implementation:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    setChecked(ss.checked);
    requestLayout();
}
```

However, `TextView` (`CompoundButton`'s ancestor) has this implementation:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }
    SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

    // ...
}
```

As you can see, `TextView` validates first if this cast will be successful, `CompoundButton` doesn't. Maybe it's a defect in Android. But still I don't see how it is possible that state has been mismatched and `AbsSavedState` has been passed to `CompoundButton` instead of `CompoundButton.SavedState`.

Comment: Did you use the same id in several layout file? You could refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961176/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-abssavedstate1-cannot-be-cast-to-and

Comment: As mentioned in post, I don’t have custom layouts, I use xaml. Also as investigated in update Xamarin seems to set ids properly. I discovered that on my devices and emulator my subclassed switch doesn’t call OnRestoreSavedInstance, even though MainActivity calls it. It seems that this issue occurs mainly on Lenovo smartphone. Maybe it’s something wrong with their OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all it looks like there must be duplicated id in preserved state, however I don't see any reasonable explanation why. Neither I can reproduce it on my devices. And as I described above:

> Xamarin.Forms sets ids automatically by increasing counter. Therefore after creating page it sets ids from `1` to `n`. After another recreation (for example after rotating screen) it sets ids from `n+1` to `2n+1`. Therefore none control will be able to restore its state, because when preserving state it will be saved as state for id=x, however after recreating Activity this control will have a different id.

Nevertheless I found a workaround to stop crashes.

```
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Switch), typeof(MyApp.Droid.CustomRenderers.CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        public CustomSwitchRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                this.Control.Id = -1;
                this.Control.SaveEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It disables state preservation for all `Switch` controls. Just in case I also set `Id = -1` to override id assigned by Xamarin. `-1` is a constant in Android which means "no id".

This workaround doesn't break state preservation in `Xamarin.Forms`, because after `Page` recreation state relies on your bindings, not Android's mechanism.

However if you would like to make it work without disabling state preservation. You can set some big id which will be constant between runs. Of course you need to set a different ID for each `Switch` therefore you may need to create a custom `Switch` and add some property like `AndroidId`. Note that id should be lower than `0x00ffffff` and big enough to avoid collisions with auto generated ids by Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

This does not address your overall question, but I believe I can shed some light on your **Update 3** section.

First let me re-state your question: why is it that `TextView` and `CompoundButton` have two different strategies for implementing `onRestoreInstanceState()`?

TextView performs conditional logic based on the particular `Parcelable` passed to it:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
>     if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
>         super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
>     super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
>     ...
> }
> ```

While CompoundButton does not:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
>     SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
>     super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
>     ...
> }
> ```

---

The reason for this is that `TextView` and `CompoundButton` have two different strategies for implementing `onSaveInstanceState()`, and so each class has a corresponding strategy to restore the state.

TextView can return two different types from `onSaveInstanceState()`:

> ```
> @Override
> public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
>     Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
>     ...
>
>     if (freezesText || hasSelection) {
>         SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
>         ...
>         return ss;
>     }
>
>     return superState;
> }
> ```

TextView will only return its own custom `SavedState` class in situations where the `super` call doesn't save everything it needs (i.e. when the TextView has been asked to freeze its text or when it has a selection). In all other cases, it just delegates to the `super` call and returns that directly.

Since `onRestoreInstanceState()` will receive whatever `onSaveInstanceState()` returned, TextView needs to be able to work when it receives either the `super` return value or its own `SavedState`.

On the other hand, CompoundButton can only return one type from `onSaveInstanceState()`:

> ```
> @Override
> public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
>     Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
>     SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
>     ss.checked = isChecked();
>     return ss;
> }
> ```

Because we know that the passed-in `state` object will always be of type `SavedState`, we don't have to do any conditional logic. We can just cast it and go.

---

Hopefully this answer provides a foundation that other answerers can build on, and perhaps eventually answer your primary question.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense, at least my worries about this place are vanished :)