# Remove and add layout dynamically by click button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on a big project and I can not solve the problem of a dynamically adding of components.I want to add layout into other layout by click on a button ADD. After this I want to remove it by click a button REMOVE.
Specially for stackoverflow I build a small example of what I want to do.
To ADD it's not a problem but remove it's a problem.When I click a "remove" button this remove not what I need (I want remove parent of "remove" button).
  After this I want to ask something more important.I will need save all this data to the DB.So I don't know how to get data from each Text Fields and put it into list (or something else) because all this  Text Fields have same ID.
So I see two way of solution:
1)Change there ID dynamically
    2)Something else))
    Thank you very much!!!

This is

> sub_fields.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
android:id="@+id/detailsLayout"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">




    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:hint="name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="phone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:id="@+id/btnAddd"
            android:onClick="onClickAddd" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="REMOVE"
            android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
            android:onClick="onClickAddd" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
android:id="@+id/generalLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#7d65258a">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="FILL FIELDS"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/subLayoutFields">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:hint="name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="phone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:onClick="onClickAdd" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
package andrey.adddinamicallycontrolsapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void onClickAdd(View view) {
        LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
       final LinearLayout subLayoutFields = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.subLayoutFields);
       final View view1 = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_fields, subLayoutFields, true);
        Button buttonRemove = (Button)view1.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);

        buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                subLayoutFields.removeView((LinearLayout)(v.getParent().getParent()));
            }});

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding some view by `addView(childView)` you should save reference to that. In that case `removeView(childView)` will work. Getting that view by traveling in view tree by `getParent()` is not a good idea.

By the way, where is your `addView` call?

Comment: `ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_fields, subLayoutFields, true);` - last flag `true` means auto-adding this view to parent (`subLayoutFields` in this case)

Comment: Ok, then do you want remove `view1`?

Comment: I don't know how to  save reference to views that I add because all the views have the same ID.I think that is why I can't remove it.

Comment: You can set ID for your inflated view by calling `view1.setId(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try `subLayoutFields.removeView(view1)` - `view1` is `final`

if you want to somehow differ your widgets (for storing in db, iterating or whatever you want) you may set for them dynamic ids using `View.generateViewId()` (API17) or using custom method from [most voted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts)

Comment: I think setting the Id of the view is the right approach.

Comment: nothing at all? have you tried logging or showing `Toast` inside `onClick`? you may need to use `subLayoutFields.requestLayout();` or `subLayoutFields.invalidate();` but I think that `removeView` call one of these methods also after removing

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!!!
The answer is :

```
public void onClickAddPanel(View view) {

            LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            LinearLayout subLayoutFieldsForBtnAdd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.productDetails);
            View view1 = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_details, subLayoutFieldsForBtnAdd, true);

}


public void onClickRemovePanel(View v) {
    View v1 = (View) v.getParent();
    LinearLayout subLayoutFieldsForBtnRemove = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.productDetails);
    subLayoutFieldsForBtnRemove.removeView(v1);
}
```

Comment: This code is also not working for me. App gets crashed on click remove button.  It shows exception like :-  Could not find method onClickAddd(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnRemove'