# How can I set a dynamic string as an Id of an Edittext Field in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having Multiple Strings, that are coming dynamically, I want to set these strings as Id of the EditText Fields in my Form. How can I do that, can you please help me?

For Ex: If I am having id "title", I want to set this title as id of the EditText Field, so that when I want to access the value of this field, I can access it like findviewById(title).

Please help me here...

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Try to use setTag and getTag.

Comment: Hope you find informative from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts/15442898#15442898)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id by reflection. For example, if you have a view in xml which has this id: `@+id/select_time` Then you can get the int value in `R`class by this way:

```
String idStr = "select_time";
    //com.example.appandroidtest is your app's package name
    Class<?> clz = com.example.appandroidtest.R.id.class;
    try {
        int viewId = (int) clz.getField(idStr).get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, But I am not having the ids defined in xml file as these strings are dynamic, Is there any way in that I can add these strings as id in xml file dynamically, so that I can use the above method that you have suggested. Thank you so much for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any way in that I can add these strings as id in xml file dynamically？--- I think this is impossible, since you cannot modify any resource file in runtime.

Comment: Do you have any alternate for this problem that I can use for solving the issue. Your help is much appreciated... Thanks.... :)

Comment: Hii, I want to set Tag for the menuitems, I am creating the menuitems dynamically using this code 
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
MenuItem menuItem = popup.getMenu().add("title");

When I am doing menuItem.getActionView().setTag("name");

It's giving me NullPointerException for this code.

Can you please guide me for this problem, so that I can set the tags for menuitems.

Thanks in advance..