# Android: programmatically setId is gives a warning Expected resource of type id

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources, android-identifiers

I don't know why it happens:

If I write the following code:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setId(1);
```

the **1** as id not working and giving me a warning like:

[image]

Its not working in following values:

```
textView.setId(0+1);   // Valid
textView.setId(var++); // Valid even var=0
```

but not valid

```
textView.setId(1);     // Invalide
```

Anyone know about this? Anyone can explain this things?

Comment: I think it is considering `+` symbol for warning as `+` is also present when giving id via xml

Comment: Why do you want to set id at all?

Comment: I just want to know why it happens. I have set id because of dynamic views. @Alexey

Comment: @VivekMishra I am getting warning when i dont give + sign.

Comment: It is because a view's id can be any positive number. In both valid cases you are passing `+` . refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1714510/6127411

Comment: @jankigadhiya I am getting warning in **1** only.

Comment: yes that' what I am trying to say as `@+id` is used in xml so it can be possible that it search for `+` in java code too

Comment: @VivekMishra no, I dont think that is problem.

Comment: you can use      textView.setId(+1);

Comment: exactly i agree with @VivekMishra , any thing you pass but with `+` it will work.

Comment: @saeed I know this thing. I want to know about why **1** is not working with it.

Comment: @jankigadhiya then why others digits are working without `+`

Comment: in my case they are not working give an example for which digit is working without `+`.

Comment: @all, I know the solution what i have to do for this. Thank you for your suggestion but My Question is different that What is the mechanism behind **1**, Why this digit not working only. Others are working

Comment: @jankigadhiya I think there is something silly reason behind this.

Comment: @PratikButani seriously no digit is working for me. i tried 454,58,2144.

Comment: @PratikButani It gives me same warning for any integer, positive or negative. Lint is just being silly, probably a regexp like `[+-]?[0-9]+`

Answer (score 1):

This warning is generated by [android lint](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/lint.html). It checks you are using the right type of ID as identifier. Signature for this function is:

```
public void setId(@IdRes int id)
```

So, lint checks you are using exactly id of type `@IdRes` (see [IdRes annotation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/annotation/IdRes.html)), not [@ColorRes](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/annotation/ColorRes.html) or [@StringRes](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/annotation/StringRes.html) (it checks you are using constants from class `R.id`)

By using expressions like `0+1` or `var++` (BTW, it's result actually is 0 not 1) you are hampering lint to infer the argument type.

Answer (score 0):

You get a warning because setting your own ID's could be dangerous, you could for example set the same ID as an already existing xml element, this will obviously collide and cause problems. Use `View.generateViewId()` instead to prevent this.

Comment: Do you think so really??

Comment: The name (android:id="...") you give to an xml element is parsed into an integer, this will be a very large number, like 28858383 or something, hypothetically speaking this makes it possible to set a duplicate id to another view programatically. by using the View.generateViewId() method you'll be sure that no ID's will collide with already existing elements. Also if I remember right, the generated ID's will start from 1 and go up.

Comment: `Possibility` you said. That will be checked on run time not compile time.