# Add indefinite number of views dynamically to a viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

The problem:

Add dynamically checkboxes to the LinearLayout.
Current range of child views 2-7, but quantity is not limited.

My first approach was pure in the code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

for (String answer : generateAnswers()) {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getContext());
    checkBox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);
    checkBox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    checkBox.setText(answer);
    mvAnswersLayout.addView(checkBox, lp);
}
```

Feels like CheckBox item should live in a xml, so second variant:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
for (String answer : generateAnswers()) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_item, mvAnswersLayout, true);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
    checkBox.setText(answer);
    checkBox.setId(General.generateViewId());
}

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        />
</merge>
```

To eliminate redundant viewgroup I use tag `<merge>` and utility [View.generateViewId()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts).

Seems the second approach is the way every android developer would expect. But what bothers me is hitting `findViewById()` multiple times (every next one will be a bit slower).

Any pros and cons?

Comment: use some "adapter" view like `ListView` or `RecyclerView` in such cases

Comment: For truly unlimited list with the need of recycling Recyclerview shines. But I'm interested in mechanics, and the next question would be why Recyclerview doesn't use <merge> tag?

Comment: what do you need <merge> for, when using with `Recyclerview`?

Comment: To eliminate redundant viewgroup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UApv-ZMJ51g

Comment: cannot you just use `<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" .... />`?

Comment: @pskink My guess it would complain.

Comment: @MikeM. True for complex items, but what's about a simple one?

Comment: you guess? if you dont want to try you will never know

Comment: @pskink Indeed, it works with RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use Recyclerview or Listview with each row as checkbox for better performance if you have many checkboxes. Also maintaining the state is also easy in recylerview or listview.

Comment: For truly unlimited list with the need of recycling Recyclerview shines. But I'm interested in mechanics, and the next question would be why Recyclerview doesn't use `<merge>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add dynamically without using RecycleView or ListView, you can create check box like below

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams checkbox_relativeParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            checkbox_relativeParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            checkbox_relativeParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getActivity());
            cb.setText("I'm dynamic!");
            cb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            cb.setTextSize(17);
            cb.setPadding(4,4,4,4);
            cb.setLayoutParams(checkbox_relativeParams);
```

and add this checkbox to the layout dynamically.

```
 this.addView(cb, checkbox_relativeParams);
```

with out request for findViewbyID(id)  always as there is only one widget in the layout.