# Create/Generate R.id on API level 16

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

This is my code simplified.

```
setOnClickListener
    _view = new View(MainActivity.this);
    _root.addView(_view);
```

I click, and a new view gets added. But i need to distinguish these view somehow. So i tired this.

```
_view.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Unfortunatly this showed up.

> Call requires API level 17 (current min is 16):
>   android.view.View#generateViewId

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Sorry, should've said this before, I need it to be on API level 16.

Comment: As stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442898 you can use `ViewCompat.generateViewId()` if your app is targeted lower than API level 17. Otherwise use `View.generateViewId()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Call requires API level 17 (current min is 16):
>   android.view.View#generateViewId

**You should increase your API level** .

```
 minSdkVersion 17// instead of 16
```

**[android:minSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)**

> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the
>   application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from
>   installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the
>   value specified in this attribute.

**I need it to be on API level 16.**

**setId(View.generateViewId())** used to identify the view . I think it will be better if you set level 17 .

Answer (score 0):

instead of View.generateViewId() you can use `view.settag(int)` to uniquely identify your view and get the view's tag using `view.getTag()`

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Tags that for something else.