# Program ImageView[][] With ID - GridLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-gridlayout

I used those code to make *2x2 Image* on a `GridLayout` and it works, but there is one problem, each `ImageView` has the same ID, `-1`, so when I use `OnClick` it does not work. What can I do?

Here the codes

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2" />
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        ImageView[][] imageViews = new ImageView[2][2];

        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
                imageViews[i][j] = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                imageViews[i][j].setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                gridLayout.addView(imageViews[i][j]);
            }
        }  
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle the `onClick` event ? What do you mean by *it does not work* ?

Comment: I think you have to manually set the ID. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts

Comment: I just wondering why won't you use `RecyclerView` or `GridView`?

Answer (score 0):

Your view IDs only need to be positive integers, so could set them like this:

```
imageViews[i][j].setId(100);   // or whatever you prefer
```

OR you could set a click listener programmaticaly:

```
// Create the click listener
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do what you want
    }
};

for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
        imageViews[i][j] = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imageViews[i][j].setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        imageViews[i][j].setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        gridLayout.addView(imageViews[i][j]);
    }
}
```