# Removing specific dynamically created EditText

Tags: android

I have a button that when a user clicks, it dynamically adds editTexts' and a clickable TextView ("X") which should delete its corresponding editText, to its layout. The number of editTexts' and TextView created are based on the number of times the button is clicked. But I now want to remove the editText when I click on the clickable TextView ("X")

```
View.OnClickListener generate = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            addEdits = new EditText(getSymptomsActivity.this);
            cancel=new TextView(getSymptomsActivity.this);
            addEdits.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(400, 79));
            addEdits.setText("");
            cancel.setText("X");
            platform.addView(addEdits);
            platform.addView(cancel);
            values.add(addEdits);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   for(int j = count; j>0 ; j--){
                       platform.removeView(addEdits);
                       //values.remove(addEdits);
                       cancel.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                   }
                }
            });
```

The issue at the moment is that, when the clickable TextView("X") is clicked it only deletes the last created editText and only that.

Comment: Pro-tips for posting: we like to trim standard boilerplate text from questions, and "please help me" is one of them. Useful reading: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255196/remove-help-please-from-titles). Additionally, since this is a help site, adding "please help" is somewhat redundant, and may be read as a form of begging.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setId()` to give `EditText` and `TextView` unique ids and call `findViewById()` when you want to remove them.

Comment: but the Views are not created through xml to have unique Ids, so wnt they conflict when the Views are created through the loop

Comment: Hi, you can have a look at this thread 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts', you can use `setTag()` in stead, it takes a string, so you can put your own stuff.

Comment: that dint help. any other ideas please?

Comment: i added `addEdits.setId(View.generateViewId());
                cancel.setId(View.generateViewId());` and `platform.removeView(addEdits.findViewById(View.generateViewId()));`

Comment: View.generateViewI‌​d() is out of your control, you can do something like 'setTag("myeditview" + i)' and use `findViewWithTag()`

Comment: still the same result