# How to callback a view created with an ID in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, generate, dynamic-view

My current scripts are

```
fun addRow(text: String, rowNum: Int){
    val textViewNm: TextView = TextView(this.context)
    textViewNm.text = text
    textViewNm.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    textViewNm.id = rowNum
    textBox.addView(textViewNm)
}
```

I'd like to callback and control textViews made by "addRow" function.

However I don't know how to call them back with ID (textViewNm.id = rowNum).

nothing showed when I tried

```
textViewNm.1 ,2 ,3 // which was rowNum
```

Comment: You could iterate through the containing layout and find the views using `childAt(position)`

Comment: @IvanWooll you could, but this wouldn't really give OP much control, would be a bit hard to know which component they'd be changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textViewNm.1 ,2 ,3 // which was rowNum
```

this won't work, because there's no property on a textView which is called 1, 2 or 3, etc.

that would be the same as using

```
textViewNm.SomeRandomPropertyWhichDoesNotExist
```

you should probably make use of another method to find these views, perhaps using `findViewById` or [finding by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366401/android-find-an-id-of-dynamically-created-view)

---

you could also consider keeping these dynamic components inside an array list and then iterating over this list

Comment: Thanks. fully understood. I will try "findViewById". -----> updated ---->  it works. I can approach them using "textBox.findViewById<TextView>(addCounter).text"

Comment: you should have a look at the tag approach i added in my answer, you might find success with that, i simply wrote this answer to explain to you why it wouldn't work