# How can I define an ID for my EditText field programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an Activity in my App that adds more EditText fields to my view when a button is clicked.

Now I want to create a new ID for every created EditText-Field. Then I want to use

```
editText.setId(createdID);
```

And then I want to add this editText to an ArrayList (thats why I need the ID!)

```
editTextList.add((EditText) findViewById(createdID));
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to set IDs when you are creating `EditText`s in code? Why can't you keep hold of references?

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. Yes, you can set ID programmatically but it has to be an `int`, it can't be a `String`. You can't do `"edittext" + String.valueOf(3)` for example. When you set IDs in XML, it all becomes `int` eventually

Comment: I cannot define the ID in references, because I dont know how many text-fields are created by the user (could be 40 etc)..

Comment: Okay, but can the int-ID be a int-variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it with **TextView.setId(int id)**.
Try to see this question for more details.
[Android: View.setID(int id) programmatically - how to avoid ID conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts)

Comment: This is so easy! And it works perfectly! Create ID with: int createdID = View.generateViewId() -- (API level 17 and above)

Answer (score 0):

Rather confusing idea. But if you really need - you can set tags to yours EditTexts

Comment: I edited my question with more detail. Is this possible with tags as well?

Comment: Well, according with your edited question - for what you are need ID here? Just add yours edittext:
list.add(new EditText(context)). 
But i think you should also dynamically add it at layout, right?

Comment: What do you mean with EditText(context)?