# How to insert in sqlite database the values of dynamic edittext fields

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext, dynamically-generated

I want to insert mobile numbers in my SQLite database the values in my edittext fields. The edittext is dynamically created once the button is clicked as shown in the screenshot. User can add multiple numbers. Currently my code is adding only one number in my database table. Please see my codes below

Main Layout code:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editNumber"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:text="Add Number"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onAddField"/>
```

Dynamic add number Layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editNumber"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Mobile Number"
    android:inputType="number" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:onClick="onDelete"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

.java code of dynamically adding of eddittext

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
}

public void onDelete(View v) {
    parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
}
```

Reference in my code of dynamically adding and removing edittext is [this](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/dynamically-add-and-remove-views-in-android/) link.

Here's my code of inserting values to database

```
if (editNumber.length() != 0) {
            boolean isInserted = myDB.addData(editNumber.getText().toString(),

            if (isInserted == true) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "All fields are required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

DatabaseHelper addData

```
public boolean addData(String number){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL1, number);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image: Image 1]

Comment: What triggers the action of adding a number to your database ?

Comment: When menu item is clicked in action bar

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating a loop for that for example:

```java
private void addAll()
{
    for(int i=0;i<parentLinearLayout.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            EditText ediNumber=(EditText)parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);

           if (editNumber.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
            boolean isInserted = myDB.addData(editNumber.getText().toString(),

            if (isInserted == true) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "All fields are required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
}
```

Try that and give a feedback

Comment: Hi sir, I tried it but its still not working only the first number is inserted and the toast is showing repeatedly.

Comment: Did you call the `addAll()` method somewhere?

Comment: I put the codes inside the onitemselect listener. I think the problem is in the edittext id. It has the same id the default edittext then the dynamically created edittext i don't know how to get the index id of each edittext

Comment: set ids dynamically on creation and save them on an array maybe

Comment: How can i set ids dynamically sir?

Comment: Follow this link I think it can help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts