# Assign ID to View with variable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am creating a table for my app where the user can add rows himself, the individual TextView elements will be clickable and open up a menu. But to do so i need the Ids of the elements.
I need to assign them with variables, so i dont have a limited amount of rows.
I also already found this solution, which works with a variable:

```
newText.setId(resources.getIdentifier("A$Row$Column", "id", this.packageName))
```

but this does always set the Id to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can set int value in your setId function..
Like your row index

`setId(rowIndex)`

For more details, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442898/6413387

Comment: But that does not work with a variable. You just can't put one in there, it won't work