# Error while selecting radio buttons after creating dynamic UI in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button

Hello to everyone i am creating a quiz app in which I am creating a dynamic UI for multiple choice question
it Works well but when i select radio button on question and then go for next question and select the radio button i gives me error **"java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton"**
Also when i change the selected option Example : First i choose option 1 of a question and then i change it to Option 2 it give me the same error
Here is the sample of my code

```
 for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setId(i);
            RadioGroup radioGroup=new RadioGroup(this);
            for(int j=0;j<=3;j++){

                RadioButton b1=new RadioButton(this);
                b1.setText("option"+j);
                b1.setId(j);
                radioGroup.addView(b1);

            }
            tv.setText("Youre question No "+i);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
            tv.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
           radioGroup.setPadding(0,5,0,0);
            linearLayout.addView(tv);
            linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {


        if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
            RadioButton uans = findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());//Error occurred here
            String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
            answersStringArray.add(ansText);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Exception :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quizapp, PID: 3428
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
        at com.example.quizapp.Paper.onCheckedChanged(Paper.java:99)//This shows where is the error
        at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:196)
        at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:59)
        at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:381)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:183)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:135)
        at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:140)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7218)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27719)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

How can i overcome this please help me guys thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tv.setId(i);` and `b1.setId(j);` - don't do that... you shouldn't use/set ids like this. all `View`s ids should (must?) be unique in whole app and in your case one `TextView` and few `RadioButton` may have same id (e.g. `1`). check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts) SO topic for more info how to set properly ids for `View`s programmatically

you are setting `id` with small `int` for both `TextView` and `RadioButton`, so when you call `findViewById` it will return first found `View` with this id - in your case `TextView`, but you are casting it to `RadioButton`...

Comment: what can i do to resolve this issue then should i enter some string along side with the id

Comment: change ids, they are duplicated. easiest way: `b1.setId(j);` -> `b1.setId(i*100+j);`, but this isn't good way, read topic linked in answer

Comment: @snachsm thank you sir youre answer helped me alot now i am using View.generateViewId() and its helps me well