# Android layout design that have two options depending on the data

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments, textview

I would like to display either 4 `textView`s or just one `editText` depending on the data that I receive from back-end

Here is my view as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/groupOfFour" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/third"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            t/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fourth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my fragment I am doing like this

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.my_fragment) {

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   val backedData = getRemoteData()
   if(backedData.hasFour()) {
     editText.visibility = Visibility.GONE
     // set the four text view
   } else {
     groupOfFour.visibility = Visibility.GONE
   }
  }
}
```

Is there any other way of achieving the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Views programmatically using `addView`

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.my_fragment) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
       val backedData = getRemoteData()

       if(backedData.hasFour()) {
            groupOfFour.addView(addTextView("Textview 1"))
         
        // set the four text view
       } else {
       
            groupOfFour.addView(addTextView("Textview 1"))
            groupOfFour.addView(addTextView("Textview 2"))
            groupOfFour.addView(addTextView("Textview 3"))
            groupOfFour.addView(addTextView("Textview 4"))

       }
    }
    
    fun addTextView(mytext: String):TextView {
        return TextView(activity).apply {
            layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            text = mytext
        }
    }  
}
```

And remove the `TextViews` from the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/groupOfFour" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   </LinearLayout>

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to set static Ids to the `TextViews`, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts#answer-22876880)