# Accessing dynamically generated view id (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I'd like to dynamically a series of views that are accessible by an id name. `ViewCompat.generateViewId` sounds like a promising way of doing so, but I have not seen a way to assign a name to that id.

I'm looking for something like this:

```java
TextView tv = new TextView(this);

tv.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId);

tv.setIdName("myTextView");
```

Is there any way to retrieve a dynamically generated resource id by a name?
Otherwise, is it possible to edit `ids.xml` to assign a name to the id?

Comment: lookout this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714510/12709358

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `tv.setId(View.generateViewId());`
And to get it just call: `tv.getId();`