# Why can't we set string ID to a view programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/googleWebview"/>
```

Here I can set an ID as the string `"googleWebview"` but if I try to use `setId()` programatically it expects an integer. Why is this?

Comment: The question is also. Why do you want to set an id at all? Is it only to find it again later? In that case you might want to use `setTag` instead of `setId`. Tags can be any object, including strings. And you can check a view's tag easily with `getTag` or search for them with `findViewWithTag` instead of `findViewById`

Comment: ohh i dont know about setTag, will check it up thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In Android all view IDs are integers - `@+id/googleWebView` is just a label for an integer ID.

In this case the `@id/` indicates that it's handling an ID reference, the `+` means that this is a new ID that should be generated. Under the hood, Android stores these generated IDs in the `R` file, and you can access reference them programmatically as `R.id.{label}`.

Comment: thanks , if am webview programatically which is not used in XML and i need to set id as string? is it possible? or do i need to generate unique id and set to it?

Comment: If it's not declared in XML at all then you can generate an ID - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts. However I don't see many use cases for this.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is build `"@+id/googleWebview"` is actually turned into an int. It will go to the `R` class. To access any ids you defined before in your xml files you can simply write `R.id.idName` in your code so in your case:

```
view.setId(R.id.googleWebview);
```

for example